# How to use Smooch postbacks?

Tags: smooch

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to actually use the postabck feature. Does it call functions on the server? What does ti do with the pasees value?

```
%[Button label here](postback:PAYLOAD_HERE) // What is the payload?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The payload is actually whatever you want!

Postback buttons can be used as triggers to your webhook. When a user taps on your postback button, a payload will be sent to your webhook with the following data:

```
{
    "trigger": "postback",
    "postbacks":[{
        ...
        "action": {
            "_id": "571530ee4fae94c32b78b170",
            "type": "postback",
            "text": "Read more",
            "payload": "YOUR_PAYLOAD_HERE" // <---- your payload!
        }
    }],
    ...
}
```

For complete payload see this reference: http://docs.smooch.io/rest/#webhooks-payload

On your side, you could have automated messages, event scheduling or anything you want.

A simple payload could be `TELL_ME_JOKE` and on your backend, you could fetch your database for a joke, then send a message through the Smooch API to reply back.

Another payload could be `RESERVE_MONDAY`. When the user taps that button, your webhook receives `RESERVE_MONDAY`. Then you could use that value to know what to do next (call into your application to reserve that time slot).

Here's a simple Node.js implementation:

```
const express = require('express');
const SmoochCore = require('smooch-core');
const smoochApi = new SmoochCore({
    keyId: 'some-key',
    secret: 'some-secret',
    scope: 'app'
});

express.Router().post('/smooch/webhooks', (req, res) => {
    const smoochPayload = req.body.postbacks[0].action.payload;
    const userId = req.body.appUser._id;

    if (smoochPayload === 'TELL_ME_JOKE') {
        smoochApi.conversations.sendMessage(userId, {
            text: 'A cow walks into a bar...',
            role: 'appMaker'
        });
    } else if (smoochPayload === 'RESERVE_MONDAY') {
        CalendarController.reserve(userId, 'monday');
    }

    res.end();
});
```

Using the payload also allows you to use different button labels, but keep the same payload (ie. different translations).

Note: it could be anything even JSON if you want!

I hope this can help you!

Answer (score -1):

The payload is what you want your bot to return. I'm not sure if my way of describing it is the best since I'm new at this. Think of it this way - If you have a button labeled `%[Yes](postback:YES)`, then when the user clicks on the button that says yes, it will be just like they typed the word "yes."

Comment: This is how the webhook is implemented in https://github.com/esthercrawford/EstherBot but it's NOT how Smooch webhooks work in general